# Dropbox API not returning all files in list

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am trying to get a full file list from my dropbox account using the python dropbox API, to later compare the local and remote folders and download only the changed files on my Raspberry PI. So for now I need the current file list on my account. I am trying to accomplish that by using this code:

```
client = dropbox.Dropbox("ACCESS_TOKEN")
metadata = client.files_list_folder("", recursive=True, include_deleted=False, include_media_info=False)
flist = []
if metadata.has_more == True:
    m1 = metadata.entries
    cur = metadata.cursor
    for i in m1:
        if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            flist.append([i.name])
    # flist now has 2000 items
    m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
    while m2.has_more == True:
        for i in m2.entries:
            if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                flist.append([i.name])
        cur = m2.cursor
        m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
```

Which gives me a total of 4971 files. But there are 5252 files in a lot of different folders (probably). I am getting a lot of different numbers. Windows gives me 5252 files using console, using the explorer it gives me 2344 files. Unix gives me 5260 files using console and 5288 files using fhe file manager...
I noticed that a lot of files are missing I added/edited recently (few days ago). After that I tried a slightly different code:

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("ACCESS_TOKEN")
result = dbx.files_list_folder("", recursive=True, include_deleted=False, include_media_info=False)
file_list = []

def process_entries(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            file_list.append([entry.name])

process_entries(result.entries)

while result.has_more:
    result = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(result.cursor)
    process_entries(result.entries)

print(len(file_list))
```

This code gives me only 1997 files, but the list is containing the new files. I don't get why this is happening, as the two codes are doing the same, but neither is capable of giving me the correct list of files.

Edit: Changed the second code accordingly to Gregs comment. Getting to many files now compared to the synchronized locale Dropbox folder.

Comment: When you say "there are 5252 files in a lot of different folders (probably)", what you do you mean by the "probably"?

Comment: Also, note that not all files from the local filesystem are synced to Dropbox. E.g., see the "Ignored files" section of: https://www.dropbox.com/help/syncing-uploads/files-not-syncing That will result in different total numbers. For that reason, comparing with the local filesystem won't work well.

Likewise, are you counting folders from the local filesystem? Your API code is only counting files, ignoring the folders themselves.

Comment: Finally, I see you copied the second code from https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started#writing%20a%20script, but your second call to `process_entries` has the wrong indentation. The way you have it, it will only run for the last page of results, and not earlier ones.

Comment: True @Greg. I changed the indentation of `process_entries` because Python gave me an indentation error for that line and I couldn't really figure out why.

Comment: I guess there is no simple way to mirror the whole dropbox using the dropbox api on the Raspberry Pi? If yes, I would not need to try it this way.

Comment: i tried second code. it's getting stuck in while loop...

Comment: Any solution to this or what?!

Comment: No, I gave up and used Google Drive with rclone instead.

Comment: is Google Drive API better?